# how to handle the "delete window" protocol on messageboxes- Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Let's say I have a message box in Python tkinter, for example:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
messagebox.showinfo("Example", "This is an example")
```

I want to be able to handle the message box's closing protocol. I know you can do it with tkinter windows, like so:

```
window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
```

But my question is how do you do it with message boxes?

Comment: don't think you can do that, you can however create your own popup window and use the `.protocol()` on that one. [some slightly outdated docs but they should stil have all the options](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/tkMessageBox.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that what I wanted to do isn't possible (with the help of @Matiiss). So what I did instead was I created a toplevel widget, added buttons to it and handled its closing protocol. Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Example")
window.state("zoomed")


def protocol_handler():
    # code


window2 = tk.Toplevel(window)
window2.geometry("300x220+500+200")
label1 = tk.Label(window2, text="Would you like to continue?")
label1.place(x=20, y=10)
button1 = tk.Button(window2, text="Yes")
button1.place(x=50, y=100)
button2 = tk.Button(window2, text="No")
button1.place(x=100, y=100)

window2.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", protocol_handler)


window.mainloop()
```